# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not recognized

Tags: ajax, web-services, sharepoint

I need get employee info from external server with JavaScript/jquery in SharePoint newform. 
First I wrote below code

```
function CallClientIDWebSerivce() {
  var URL = "http://applicationsrv/HRMServices.asmx/GetEmployeeInfo";
  alert(URL)
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: URL,
      dataType: "xml",                     
      data:"userName:"+username+",date:"+today()+",modified_by:"+username+"}" ,          
      contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
          success: function (response) {
          alert(response);
      },
      failure: function (msg) {
          alert('failure');
          dialog.innerHTML = "Some Unknown Error Occured, Please Try Again";
      }
  });
}
```

and get error

> `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.`

I google it I found out it occurs for [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
 so i added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*",` to ajax but browsers don`t recognize it and get error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything on the client. Browser does it automatically. But the Share Point should be configured to allow requests for script that originates from other domains.
Look here how you can **configure Share Point**:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/8dfc2b5e-1136-45a8-9d85-73ce9c98fd06/how-to-enable-cors-on-sharepoint-online-site?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: thank you, but I do work on SharePoint on-primes not sharepoin online

Comment: What you mean by "not online"? You wrote in your question that you need "info from external server". Means, this series is online. And this server does not allow browsers to send requests to it if the script come from another (from your) site. The solution is to set proper headers on the sharepoint server to allow it accept scripts from other servers. If you have no control of that sharepoint server, thènnthere is no solution in browser only. An alternative can be, that your browser sends request to YOUR server, which requests then the sharepoint server.